# Django static files and pull requests from git repo

Tags: python, django, git, static, digital-ocean

My question is:

When I am developing on localhost and adding a bunch of static files(images), what is the best way to get those files to the server which is hosted on DigitalOcean?
Right now I have a git repo to which I do push and pull requests, but in my .gitignore I have /static ignored is from the udemy course "Django 2.2 and Python - The Ultimate Web Development Bootcamp" by Nick Walter. I can not find any information, other than that, on what is the best practice.

```
#.gitignore
*.log
*.pot
*.pyc
__pycache__/
local_settings.py
db.sqlite3
db.sqlite3-journal
/media
/static
```

Comment: Which tutorial did you read for "/static/ ignored"?

Comment: Django 2.2 by Nick Walter